# Solving differential equation by using Bernoulli method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the following equation by using the Bernoulli method. 
$$
2\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{1}{x}y=x^2y^{-1}
$$

So if I'm understanding right, I divide the former by $y^{-1}$ to get:
$$
2y\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{1}{x}y^2=x^2
$$
Then let $v=y^2$, thus $v'=2y\frac{dy}{dx}$, and substituting these values I get: 
$$
v'+\frac{1}{x}v=x^2
$$
And here's where I'm stuck. The book I'm reading says I should find a $f(x)$ such that:
$$
f(x)=e^{\int{(1-n)p(x)dx}}
$$
I think $n=-1$ and $p(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ so I'm looking for an $f$ such that: 
$$
f(x)=e^{\int{2\frac{1}{x}dx}}
$$
Is that correct? How should I proceed from here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: your n here is actually $n=0$. So the only integral left is literally just $f(x) = x$. Then multiply both sides by $f(x) = x$ and then solve normally as linear. (anti product rule integration etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integrating factor for $$v'+\frac{1}{x}v=x^2$$ is $\mu =x$ because $$ e^{\int \frac {1}{x}dx} = e^{\ln x }=x$$

Thus multiply $$v'+\frac{1}{x}v=x^2$$ by $x$ and go from there.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I think I got it, I didn't relate $e^{\int{\frac{1}{x}dx}}$ to be the integrating factor $\mu$, so if I'm correct I get $xv'+(1)v=x^3$ thus $\int{(xv)'}dx=\int{x^3dx}$ which eventually turns into $xv=\frac{x^4}{4}+C$. So substituting v, I get $xy^2=\frac{x^4}{4}+C$ which should be the solution. I hope :)

Comment: Yes you are correct.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Don't go by formulas. Understand the fact that it is a linear differential equation now and solve it like that.

For this linear differential equation,
$$y'+P(x)y=Q(x)$$

The integrating factor is defined to be

$$f(x)=e^{\int P(x)dx}$$

It is like that because multiplying both sides by this turns the LHS into the derivative of the function $y\times f(x)$.

Hence, solution is

$$y\times f(x)=\int Q(x)f(x)dx$$

Hope it helps:)

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, I didn't notice that it was a linear equation, from that getting the integrating factor and then doing the integration on both sides made it easier, once I understood that well. Thanks again!